# MudDatePicker shows month number instead of month in drop down

Tags: blazor, mudblazor

I have set up a MudDatePicker that is ignoring all attempts to get the culture right.  The culture I need is Norwegian bokmål.  No matter what I choose, it shows December as M12, for example. No culture works, even ones taken right from the examples.

This is a Blazor WASM project.

```
<MudDatePicker Label="Startdato"  Culture="@CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("zh-Hans")" @bind-Date="@StartDate" />
<MudDatePicker Label="Sluttdato" ShowWeekNumbers="true" Culture="@CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("no-Nb")" @bind-Date="@EndDate" />
```

It looks like this:
[image]

Comment: it's working as expected [snippet](https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet/GkQxFQwCnFqPKaKt) there's probably something else causing this issue for you and that can't be answered with the current amount of info you've provided so far in the question.

Comment: @RBee - Thanks for setting up the snippet.  Very cool, didn't know that could be done.  And - take a look at the top one, it is supposed to be Chinese.  Why isn't the selected culture kicking in? If we can solve that, then that maybe would point me in the right direction.

Comment: the environment the snippet website is running on probably doesn't support it or limited functionality. How to setup a custom culture with the dates and months changed are in the docs https://mudblazor.com/components/datepicker#internationalization

Comment: Fair enough.  I will dig in and see what I can figure out.  Thanks for the tips so far.